# Get current hour unix timestamp

Tags: c++, c, timestamp

I'd like to get the unix timestamp of the beginning of current (or any given maybe) hour in c/c++.

I have this:

```
    time_t get_current_hour() {
        time_t beginning_of_hour;
        struct tm * ptm;

        time(&beginning_of_hour);

        ptm = gmtime(&beginning_of_hour);
        ptm->tm_min = 0;
        ptm->tm_sec = 0;
        ptm->tm_zone = (char*) "GMT";

        beginning_of_hour = mktime(ptm);

        return beginning_of_hour;
    }
```

Which works, but under high load many of the result are not the beginning of the current hour but the actual time.

Is there a better way to solve the problem?
Why does the function returns the current time?

Please advise,
   Akos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that you have a multi-threaded application, and calls to `gmtime` are not thread-safe (re-entrant). If this is the case, try using the re-entrant version: `gmtime_r`

Comment: Well, you have the point. The app is multithreaded indeed. Thanks, I'll use gmtime_r.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it all with `time_t`, without breaking it apart and rebuilding.
Just round it down to a multiple of 3600:

```
time_t get_current_hour(void) {
    time_t now;
    time(&now);
    return now - (now % 3600);
}
```

Perhaps it isn't nice to treat `time_t` as an integer. But I think it is guaranteed to be seconds since the epoch, so it should be fine.

Comment: `time_t` is only guaranteed to be a numeric type, so it could be `double` (not that I've ever seen such a thing).

Comment: @JamesKanze: That is going to play hell on precision in a couple of thousand years when we start loosing the last couple of bits of an int.

Comment: @JamesKanze, this code works as long as `now+1 == now` is never true. Defining `time_t` that allows that seems quite bad to me.

Comment: @LokiAstari The 32 bit int for seconds since 1970 will overflow long before that.

Comment: @ugoren The one case I've seen where time was represented as a `double` (not a `time_t`, but in a separate library), the integral values were days.  So while `now + 1 !@= now`, it likely isn't the result you'd expect.  It's interesting that the standard defines a `difftime`, which returns a `double`, but it doesn't provide anything to add seconds (or days, or whatever) to a `time_t`.  I guess you're supposed to use `localtime`, manipulate the `tm` and then `mktime` to do that.

Comment: And just to be very clear: I'd probably use @ugoren's idea myself.  The standard says it isn't portable, but I suspect that in reality it is (and if you do hit upon the exception, it won't compile, so you can fix it then).

Comment: @JamesKanze: A single precision float (32 bit) would have overflowed the integer part before 1971. So if we consider 64 bit models. The integer version will last 0.5 trillion years while the double version will only last 0.1 Billion years. All calculations done on a napkin over breakfast :-)

Comment: @LokiAstari Except that on all of the Unix systems I've seen, `time_t` is a 32 bit int, not a 64 bit one.  And the only case where I've seen a non-integral time and date (not a `time_t`), it was a `double` representing days.  So the integral format will overflow shortly (less than 30 years), but the `double` format won't.  (For that matter, even `float` won't overflow.  But the precision will be pretty bad---worse even than the old MS-DOS machines which only returned the number of seconds divided by 2.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Sorry by `overflow the integer part` I meant this is the point at which we start loosing precision.

Comment: @LokiAstari Well, we loose some precision almost immediately.  If I only need one digit for the day, then I have something like 16 left, which gives a precision of around a nanosecond; a year later, I'll only have a precision of around a 100 nanoseconds.  (More or less---I've not worked it out precisely.)  It's sort of weird, and I don't think I'd like to see it used for a `time_t`, but it is certainly legal according the C standard.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I just feel sorry for the utopian society that we have formed when in .1 Billion years there computers fall apart. Not because of the inaccuracy in the time const but the fact they are still using stuff written in C/C++ :-)

Answer (score 0):

Is your application by any chance multi-threaded?  `gmtime` returns a
pointer to static memory, which will be overwritten the next time the
function is called.  Such functions are not thread-safe (and this is
about the only thing I can think of which would account for your
symptoms).  Under Unix, there is also a `gmtime_r`, which allows you to
declare a local buffer, and avoid the issue; Windows has a `_gmtime_s`
which is (I think) similar.

Comment: Thank you for your response, you are right. The app is multi threaded, I'll use gmtime_r